# Return the same response model on two different endpoints on FastAPI

Tags: python, fastapi

I am using FastAPI and I cannot view the documentation on the /docs endpoint when I have the same response model for two endpoints.

This is the code I use

```
import dataclasses

import fastapi
import uvicorn

app = fastapi.FastAPI()



@dataclasses.dataclass
class Response:
    yo: str


@app.post('/one', response_model=Response)
def get_responses():
    pass


@app.post('/two', response_model=Response)  # When I remove this "Response", or I create a second class it works.
def send_responses():
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run(app, host='127.0.0.1')
```

This is the error it shows in the browser
[image]

This is the error it shows in the code

```
...
response = await func(request)
  File "E:\Code\venvs\lib\site-packages\fastapi\applications.py", line 224, in openapi
    return JSONResponse(self.openapi())
  File "E:\Code\venvs\lib\site-packages\fastapi\applications.py", line 199, in openapi
    self.openapi_schema = get_openapi(
  File "E:\Code\venvs\lib\site-packages\fastapi\openapi\utils.py", line 418, in get_openapi
    definitions = get_model_definitions(
  File "E:\Code\venvs\lib\site-packages\fastapi\utils.py", line 32, in get_model_definitions
    model_name = model_name_map[model]
KeyError: <class 'pydantic.dataclasses.Response'>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is something weird going on with dataclasses in FastAPI. I haven't been able to put my finger on it, but there are others with the same problem, for example https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/5138

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, I'll observe that topic in the link you mentioned. I assume the issue could be solved by using pydantics BaseModel instead of the dataclasses. I'll try that tomorrow

Comment: Yes definitely, it is a specific issue to dataclasses. Base model works as expected!

Comment: If you use fastapi there is no point using basic dataclasses, you should use pydantic models as it is shipped with the framework

Comment: With BaseModel it does work indeed. @BastienB I usually prefer dataclasses due to better IDE support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize the comments: currently FastAPI seems to have problems when re-using the same dataclass. The solution would be to use the BaseModel of pydantic instead.

Below is the full working code, the only change is how the class "Response" is declared.

```
import dataclasses

import fastapi
import uvicorn
import pydantic


app = fastapi.FastAPI()


class Response(pydantic.BaseModel):
    yo: str


@app.post('/one', response_model=Response)
def get_responses():
    pass


@app.post('/two', response_model=Response)
def send_responses():
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run(app, host='127.0.0.1')
```